# How to find if a company (customer) ordered in a particular month and year and never before? (MySQL)

Tags: sql, mysql

This would be considered a "new shop open" in that particular month and year.  Say company Store123 placed their first order in January, 2023 and it checks if Store123 ordered before that.  If the company did not than Store123 would be considered a "new shop open" starting in January 2023.

I only have one table with Columns:

| **Company | Order ID | Close Date | Amount** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Store123 | 00018972 | 2023-04-26 | 2880 |
| StoreABC | 00017237 | 2023-01-05 | 3720 |
| Store123 | 00018242 | 2023-01-03 | 4280 |
| StoreABC | 00017123 | 2022-06-05 | 3231 |

This should return:

**Store123 | 00018242 | 2023-01-03 | 4280**

My logic is somewhat like this, even though this query isn't working

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
WHERE MIN(Close Date) 
  BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-01-31'
GROUP BY 'Company';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the query below

```
-- New Shop Open
SELECT *
FROM Orders o
WHERE `Close Date` >= '2023-01-01' AND `Close Date` < '2023-02-01'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Orders
        WHERE Company = o.Company AND `Close Date` < '2023-01-01' 
    )
```

Comment: That worked flawlessly.  You are a SQL beast thank you sir!

Comment: Please mark it as answered so that it can be removed from the queue.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a partitioning function ROW_NUMBER().

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/

What you can do is simply partition by the "group by" in your case and order by the date.  This way anything that returns as a value of 1 is the first instance of the store being active.

If you need to filter via a date situation, you can then take your table of data and join back to it to get your answer.

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    CompanyTable T 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COMPANY ORDER BY CLOSE_DATE) AS RN 
    FROM 
        CompanyTable ) X 
    ON X.Company = T.Company 
    AND X.RN = 1 
WHERE 
    T.CLOSE_DATE BETWEEN <startdate> and <enddate>
```

Please note, since I'm not 100% sure what you're aiming for the code above is just a rough estimate to the answer.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because you cant combine the MIN function with the BETWEEN operator. Answers in SQL always return sets, not single results, that's what is always to be taken into account. So the first thing is: you might want to know the Company, and then you could think about that there are no orders before that particular month.
The other thing to remember is, SQL engines work differently. Oracle likes to get queries with "where not exists" and outer joins, while SQL-Server likes embedded subqueries. Mysql on the other hand more likely selects along ordering and eliminating rows.
So it really depends on the server you are using. There is no solution that will work everywhere with any ammount of data. sorry.